# How to rerender 'Select a spec' at swagger in Java platform?

Tags: java, swagger, render

> I would like to rerender *'Select a spec'* `comboBox` with different
>   values for each user.

For example: `X` platform users can see `n` different options and `Y` platform users can see `m` different options.

Every platform user will use a different url extension. (E.g.: `swagger.url/xPlatform` and `swagger.url/yPlatform`)

**Is there a way to do this?**

For now, I don't use `user type` in my project. But if I can rerender the `comboBox`, I will start more development for this.

**I'm open to new suggestions for this mechanism.**